# Find the values of $x$ for which $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{\cos(3^n.x)}{2^n})$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My attempt :
$$V(n,x)=\displaystyle \frac{\cos(3^{n+1}x).2^n}{2^{n+1}.\cos(3^nx)}.$$ If I can show that $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} V(n,x)< 1$ then I am done . Now $$\frac{-1}{2}< \frac{\cos(3^{n+1}x)}{2}<\frac{1}{2}.$$ How should I proceed from here?

Comment: Note that we have$$-\frac1{2^n}\le\frac{\cos{(3^nx)}}{2^n}\le\frac1{2^n}$$so the series converges $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It seems that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \big| \frac{\cos(3^n x)}{2^n} \big| \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} < \infty$. So it converges for all $x$.

Comment: The problem is that $\cos(3^n x)$ can sometimes be zero and you should avoid dividing by it.

Comment: Are you sure about the problem statement ? It looks too easy.

Answer (score 3):

It converges for every $x$ since $|\cos\theta|\leq1$ for all $\theta$. Then you can use comparison test against a geometric series.